# Formik Reset callback creates recursive issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I have a very simple formik setup where I need to pass the new initial values when users press reset form button. I am following doc but I end up creating recursive issue.

`formReset()` is passed to formik as a param of `onReset`. The function is called but I am not sure where is the recursion happening.

[Here is a codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-example-forked-02wg0?file=/index.js) for your convenient. Change form value then try to reset the form.

### App.js

```
// Helper styles for demo
import "./helper.css";
import { MoreResources, DisplayFormikState } from "./helper";

import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { Formik } from "formik";
import * as Yup from "yup";

const formReset = (_, {resetForm}) => {
  resetForm({email: ''});
}

const App = () => (
  <div className="app">
    <h1>
      Basic{" "}
      <a
        href="https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik"
        target="_blank"
        rel="noopener noreferrer"
      >
        Formik
      </a>{" "}
      Demo
    </h1>

    <Formik
      initialValues={{ email: "populate@test.com" }}
      
      onSubmit={async values => {
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 500));
        alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
      }}
      onReset={formReset}
      validationSchema={Yup.object().shape({
        email: Yup.string()
          .email()
          .required("Required")
      })}
    >
      {props => {
        const {
          values,
          touched,
          errors,
          dirty,
          isSubmitting,
          handleChange,
          handleBlur,
          handleSubmit,
          handleReset
        } = props;
        return (
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <label htmlFor="email" style={{ display: "block" }}>
              Email
            </label>
            <input
              id="email"
              placeholder="Enter your email"
              type="text"
              value={values.email}
              onChange={handleChange}
              onBlur={handleBlur}
              className={
                errors.email && touched.email
                  ? "text-input error"
                  : "text-input"
              }
            />
            {errors.email && touched.email && (
              <div className="input-feedback">{errors.email}</div>
            )}

            <button
              type="button"
              className="outline"
              onClick={handleReset}
              disabled={!dirty || isSubmitting}
            >
              Reset
            </button>
            <button type="submit" disabled={isSubmitting}>
              Submit
            </button>

            <DisplayFormikState {...props} />
          </form>
        );
      }}
    </Formik>

    <MoreResources />
  </div>
);

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Answer (score 2):

## Edit:

So... a better option would be to use `initialValues` in `useState` and pass `enableReinitialize` and change the state to "reset" the form. It's more easy than trying to use `resetForm`.

---

You don't need to pass a function to `onReset` and call `resetForm`, you can do that by just pass the type `reset` to the button and have the `Form` component instead of normal html `form` tag.

The `Form` component will handle the `handleReset` that will be trigger when you have a `button` with `type="reset"`.

```
<Form>
    {/* other components */}
    <button
      type="reset"
      className="outline"
      disabled={!dirty || isSubmitting}
    >
      Reset
    </button>
</Form>
```

Here is a [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-example-forked-mvfve).

Comment: I need to reset to something other then the previous initialized value. If you see my reset function you will notice I am passing an object to `resetForm()`.

Comment: @Sisir Please take a look at my edit. If you want to call `resetForm({email: ''})` just get the function from the formik and call in the `onClick`. Very simple. I have also update my working example

Comment: Thanks for your effort but It still resets to the initial value (could you check?) passed to `<Formik />` not the one that passed using `resetForm()`. However I was about to make it work by storing the initial state in local state using `useState()` with combination with `enableReinitialize`. Not the solution I wanted but I can not get the formik reset to work.

Comment: @Sisir I think that is the easiest approach. While reading the docs, I can't really understand what is that `resetForm` for. I would use `enableReinitialize` too in that case.